# Shiny: plot results in popup window

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a web app with shiny and I would like to display the resulting plot of a R function in a popup 
window rather than in mainPanel.
For instance, for the below example (from http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html), clicking on "Go" button 
would show the same plot but in a popup window.

I tried to add some javascript, but I have not succeeded yet... Can anyone help ?

Thank you in advance !

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("go", "Go"),
    numericInput("n", "n", 50),
 plotOutput("plot")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
  runif(input$n)
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
   hist(randomVals())
 })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look into `shinyBS` package which offers `modal` popups. Example below shows the plot upon button click.

**EDIT - Added a download button to the Modal**

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

shinyApp(
  ui =
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(numericInput("n", "n", 50),actionButton("go", "Go")),
        mainPanel(
          bsModal("modalExample", "Your plot", "go", size = "large",plotOutput("plot"),downloadButton('downloadPlot', 'Download'))
        )
      )
    ),
  server =
    function(input, output, session) {

      randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
        runif(input$n)
      })

      plotInput <- function(){hist(randomVals())}

      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        hist(randomVals())
      })

      output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "Shinyplot.png",
        content = function(file) {
          png(file)
          plotInput()
          dev.off()
        }) 

    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, it works perfectly !  If I can ask one more thing, how do you add a button to download the plot ? I try to add directly a line in html like: `<div class="modal-footer">  <a id="downloadData" class="shiny-download-link" href="" target="_blank" >Download</a>   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>   </div>` but it does not display...

Comment: I edited my answer to include the download button, happy coding!

Comment: Thank you again ! I tried first in this way but it did not work. I try again with your code and it works perfectly... I should have a mistake in the code just above... Solved now ! Thank you.

Comment: Fantastic this can be done and great answer. Any idea how to get this also to work with a `plotly_click` event? Can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @Gopala, maybe you can create a question, I can look into it with your example. Please be explicit what you want to achieve, I can write a bit of `Javascript` to complete it too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897594/use-bsmodal-in-the-shinybs-package-with-plotly-r-plotly-click-to-generate-new-pl

Answer (score 8):

Using native Shiny functionality

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  numericInput("n", "n", 50)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    runif(input$n)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(randomVals())
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      plotOutput("plot"),
      footer = NULL,
      easyClose = TRUE
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: modal demo]

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [conditional panel](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html) to show/hide an [absolute panel](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/absolutePanel.html) containing your plot, setting the condition to some js variable toggled by a function attached to your button .

e.g.

```
conditionalPanel("popupActive==1",
                        absolutePanel(id = "popup", class = "modal", 
                                      fixed = FALSE, draggable = TRUE,
                                      top = 200, right = "auto", left = 400, 
                                      bottom = "auto",
                                      width = 500, height = 500,
                        plotOutput(#output plot stuff#)
                        )
                        )
```

Then toggle the value of popupActive in js to show/hide

```
  HTML('<head><script>popupActive = 0; function myFunction(){popupActive=!popupActive;} </script></head>'), HTML('<button id="go" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button" onclick="myFunction()">Go</button>'),
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. However, I'm newbie in shiny/javascript/etc. and I try  to add `HTML('<head><script> function myFunction(){popupActive=1;} </script></head>'),
  HTML('<button id="go" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button" onclick="myFunction()">Go</button>') ` but it still does not work. And the value of popupActive should be toggled to 0  when popup window is closed... Excuse my ignorance, but may I ask you a more explicit (i.e. with js) answer ?

Comment: Pork Chops answer is the way to go; shinyBS looks like a really useful package. For completeness though I've edited my answer to include an example of the some js that would work. The only modification you needed was to create the popActive global variable, and then to toggle it on button clicks... `popupActive=!popupActive`