# Use bsModal in the shinyBS package with plotly R plotly_click to generate new plot in pop up

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shinybs

Here is my code for a basic shiny app using `plotly_click` event to optionally show another plot. I would like that side box plot to render in a modal pop up instead of on the side within the page.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(rep('a', 10), rep('b', 10)),
                  y = c(rnorm(10), rnorm(10, 3, 1)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6, plotlyOutput('scatter')),
  column(6, plotlyOutput('box'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scatter <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(df1, x = x, y = y, mode = 'markers', source = 'scatter')
  })

  output$box <- renderPlotly({
    eventdata <- event_data('plotly_click', source = 'scatter')
    validate(need(!is.null(eventdata),
                  'Hover over the scatter plot to populate this boxplot'))


    plot_ly(df2, x = x, y = y, type = 'box')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I was able to follow this question ([Shiny: plot results in popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925430/shiny-plot-results-in-popup-window/33933549?noredirect=1#comment61356351_33933549)) and response, and tried to use it with the `trigger` of `plotly_click` without success. Any idea how to pull the same thing off with a plotly hover click event?

UPDATE: I can clearly see that a `plotly` plot can be rendered in a `shinyBS` modal pop up window as demonstrated by this code.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('go', 'Click Go'),
  bsModal('plotlyPlot', 'Here is a Plot', 'go', plotlyOutput('scatter1'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scatter1 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(df2, x = x, y = y, mode = 'markers', source = 'scatter1')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Instead of an `actionButton` as the trigger, I want the `plotly_click` or `plotly_hover` as there trigger (in the original example).

Comment: Are you comfortable working with JS and CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `toggleModal`, just add this to your server:

```
observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "scatter"), {
 toggleModal(session, "boxPopUp", toggle = "toggle")
})
```

and put the box Plot in an bsModal (Title and trigger is empty):

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6, plotlyOutput('scatter')),
  bsModal('boxPopUp', '', '', plotlyOutput('box'))
)
```

**UPDATE:** with shiny-build-in Modal functionality (since Shiny 0.14), only the server addition is needed:

```
 observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "scatter"), {
                showModal(modalDialog(
                        renderPlotly({
                                plot_ly(df2, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'box')
                        })
                ))
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using CSS

You can use [`HTML builder`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/builder.html) to contain the plots and use stylesheet to add dynamic effects.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  includeCSS(path_to_css_file),
  div( class='mainchart',
    column(6, plotlyOutput('scatter')),
    div(  class='popup',
        column(6, plotlyOutput('box'))
       )
    )
)
```

CSS

```
div.popup {
   display : none;
   position: absolute;
}
div.mainchart : focus > div.popup {
   display : block;
}
div.mainchart {
   position: relative;
}
```

### Using Javascript

You can use the plotly [embeded-API](https://github.com/plotly/postMessage-API) to set the visibility of your side box.

### shinyBS

Since you want to stick to shinyBS, you can use the `bsPopover` function with a little trick.  I assume you already know how to use [`bsModel`](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Modals.html#bsModal) which is similar to the example below.

Pass the following argument to `fluidPage`

```
bsTooltip(id, title, placement = "bottom", trigger = "click", content=column(6, plotlyOutput('box'))  )
```

This will create the plot with a `Popover` wraper. I didn't test it yet. In case of error, you can also try

```
options = list()
options$content = column(6, plotlyOutput('box'))
options$html = T # otherwise the conent will be converted to text
bsTooltip(id, title, placement = "bottom", trigger = "click",  options=options  )
```

Visit this [source file](https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS/blob/67ba9a262115aba974f2f0ab0d11095aee839b53/R/Tooltips_and_Popovers.R)  of shinyBS and the [popover(options)](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/#popoveroptions) function of `bootstrap` for more info.

Comment: Thank you. I really want to avoid doing HTML/CSS. Additionally, not sure if this will invoke the other plot 'feeding' the data from the click on the hover point. In the first plotly plot, I will be hovering over a specific data point and presenting additional detail about data pertaining to that plot. I simplified the example above to focus the problem.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to show side box only when hovering on specific data points? Is Javascript acceptable for you?

Comment: That is correct. I have `index` of the point hovered over (or clicked - actually I am using `plotly_click`) and I have another table I index into with this point number and then present the box plot. In the above example, I just have a single data set for box plot to keep things simple. As for JS, I don't mind, but I am really trying to find a way to use shinyBS + Shiny + Plotly as cleanly as possible.

Comment: It would be not a very nice solution to the problem but you could maybe try to create a dynamic `actionButton` which activates `bsModal` conditional on `plotly_click`. Then auto-click it and hide :) Yea...it is a bad idea :)