# shiny Popover and print table in content of popover

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, popover

I would like to have a popover and in the content to print a table(which in my case is named out).
I have the table which looks like data.frame but when I run the command typeof(out),
I get "list"

[image]

I have tried with the following code

```
addPopover(session=session, id="infocpbayestext", title="", 
         content=HTML(out), placement = "left",
         trigger = "hover", options = list(html = "true"))
```

And with

```
addPopover(session=session, id="infocpbayestext", title="", 
         content=HTML(build_infocpbayes_table(out)), placement = "left",
         trigger = "hover", options = list(html = "true"))
```

where build_infocpbayes_table is a function that tries to build a html table like this

```
"<table><tr><th>index</th><th>Date</th><th>Count</th><th>postprob</th></tr><tr> <td>..</td> <td>..</td> <td>...</td> <td>...</td> </tr></table>"
```

But although I build the correct string as above it does not appear in popover.

Any idea how could I do that?

**Edit**
To give a better view of my code

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
output$infocpbayestext <- renderUI ({
  out<-structure(list(Date = c("2003-12", "2007-09", "2007-11"), Count =c(8721L,+ 31341L, 42948L), postprob = c(1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(174L,+ 219L,221L), class = "data.frame") 
addPopover(session=session, id="infocpbayestext", title="", content=HTML(build_infocpbayes_table(out)), placement = "left", trigger = "hover", options = list(html = "true"))
  return(HTML('<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">i</button>'))


})
build_infocpbayes_table <- function(data){
    html.table <- paste('<table style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 1%; width: 300px;"><tr><th>index</th><th>Date</th><th>Count</th><th>postprob</th></tr><tr>',tags$td(HTML(paste0(rownames(data),collapse=""))),
                  tags$td(HTML(paste0(data$Date,collapse=""))),
                  tags$td(HTML(paste0(data$Count,collapse=""))),
                  tags$td(HTML(paste0(data$postprob,collapse=""))),
                '</tr></table>')
    return(html.table)
}})

shinyUI(uiOutput("infocpbayestext"))
```

Comment: hi, can you include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @bretauv I have added an edit, with more code but it is not reproducable because of the table "out" that I have posted as an image in the thread post

Comment: why don't you use ```dput``` to generate the table ```out``` instead of putting an image?

Comment: ok thank you I didn't know that, I am new in R. You could check now

Comment: @bretauv any idea now with the updated code?

Comment: you should look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925430/shiny-plot-results-in-popup-window) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45151436/shiny-datatable-popup-data-about-selected-row-in-a-new-window)