# Leaflet fullscreen toggle/button in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to create a `time series` visualization via `leaflet` with a slider in `R Shiny`. The app works fine. As an additional step, I am trying to add a `toggle/button` which the user can click and the `map` will then load in `fullscreen`.

How can I add a button functionality to toggle the map display in fullscreen and then upon clicking it again to back to the original/default size?

Code

```
# This is a Shiny time series map web application
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(leaflet)
library(xts)


xts_to_tibble <- function(xts_obj) {
  data.frame(index(xts_obj), coredata(xts_obj)) %>%
    set_names(c("date", names(xts_obj))) %>%
    as_tibble()
}

# Create sample data
Date <- c(
  "2014-04-08", "2014-06-04", "2014-04-30",
  "2014-05-30", "2014-05-01"
)
lat <- as.numeric(c(
  "45.53814", "45.51076", "45.43560", "45.54332",
  "45.52234"
))
lon <- as.numeric(c(
  "-73.63672", "-73.61029", "-73.60100",
  "-73.56000 ", "-73.59022"
))
id <- as.numeric(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))

# Create a df from the above columns
df <- data.frame(id, lat, lon, Date)
df$Year <- lubridate::year(df$Date)
df$Month <- lubridate::month(df$Date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
df$Week <- lubridate::week(df$Date)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Title
  titlePanel("Time Series Visiualization Map"),
  sidebarLayout(

    # Define the sidebar
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons(
        inputId = "Frequency",
        label = " Select Time Series Frequency",
        choices = c(
          "weeks",
          "months",
          "years"
        ),
        selected = "weeks",
        inline = T
      ),
      uiOutput("Time_Series_UI")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("Time_Series_Map")
    ),
  )
)



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Render slider input depending on data frequency

  observe({
    # Create an xts object
    df_xts <- xts(df, order.by = as.Date(df$Date))

    # All_Dates = unique(df$Start_Date)

    Filtered_Dates <- df_xts[xts::endpoints(
      df_xts,
      on = input$Frequency
    )] %>% xts_to_tibble()

    output$Time_Series_UI <- renderUI({
      sliderInput("Date", "Date:",
        min = pull(slice_min(Filtered_Dates, date), date),
        max = pull(slice_max(Filtered_Dates, date), date),
        value = pull(slice_min(Filtered_Dates, date), date),
        step = 1,
        #timeFormat = "%YYYY-%MM-%DD",
        animate = T
      )
    })
  })

  # Filter data for the date selected
  Filtered_Data <- reactive({
    req(input$Date)
    filter(df, Date == input$Date)
  })


  # Create the leaflet map
  output$Time_Series_Map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(df) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lat = 0, lng = 0, zoom = 2)
  })

  # Create data markers for selected date
  observe({
    # print(input$Date)

    leafletProxy("Time_Series_Map", data = Filtered_Data()) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(
        lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat,
        popup = ~id
      )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```r
# This is a Shiny time series map web application
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(xts)


xts_to_tibble <- function(xts_obj) {
    data.frame(index(xts_obj), coredata(xts_obj)) %>%
        set_names(c("date", names(xts_obj))) %>%
        as_tibble()
}

# Create sample data
Date <- c(
    "2014-04-08", "2014-06-04", "2014-04-30",
    "2014-05-30", "2014-05-01"
)
lat <- as.numeric(c(
    "45.53814", "45.51076", "45.43560", "45.54332",
    "45.52234"
))
lon <- as.numeric(c(
    "-73.63672", "-73.61029", "-73.60100",
    "-73.56000 ", "-73.59022"
))
id <- as.numeric(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))

# Create a df from the above columns
df <- data.frame(id, lat, lon, Date)
df$Year <- lubridate::year(df$Date)
df$Month <- lubridate::month(df$Date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
df$Week <- lubridate::week(df$Date)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
ui <- fluidPage(
    htmltools::htmlDependencies(icon("", verify_fa = FALSE)),
    tags$style(
        '
        .plot-zoom {
            position: absolute;
            border: none;
            background-color: transparent;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .full-screen {
            position: fixed;
            height: 100vh !important;
            width: 100vw !important;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 9999;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        .leaflet-full-screen {
            position: relative;
        }
        '
    ),
    # Title
    titlePanel("Time Series Visiualization Map"),
    sidebarLayout(
        
        # Define the sidebar
        sidebarPanel(
            radioButtons(
                inputId = "Frequency",
                label = " Select Time Series Frequency",
                choices = c(
                    "weeks",
                    "months",
                    "years"
                ),
                selected = "weeks",
                inline = T
            ),
            uiOutput("Time_Series_UI")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            div(
                class = "leaflet-full-screen",
                leafletOutput("Time_Series_Map")
            )
           
        ),
    ),
    tags$script(HTML(
        "
        function plotZoom(el){
            el = $(el);
            var parent = el.parent().parent();
            if(el.attr('data-full_screen') === 'false') {
                parent.addClass('full-screen')
                      .css('position', '')
                      .trigger('resize').fadeOut().fadeIn();
                el.attr('data-full_screen', 'true');
            } else {
                parent.removeClass('full-screen')
                      .css('position', 'relative')
                      .trigger('resize').fadeOut().fadeIn();
                el.attr('data-full_screen', 'false');
            }
        }
        
        $(function(){
           $('.leaflet-full-screen  .leaflet.html-widget').append(
            `
            <div class='plot-zoom'>
                <button onclick=plotZoom(this)  data-full_screen='false' title='Full screen'>
                    <i class='fa fa-expand-arrows-alt'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            `); 
        })
        "
    ))
)



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # Render slider input depending on data frequency
    
    observe({
        # Create an xts object
        df_xts <- xts(df, order.by = as.Date(df$Date))
        
        # All_Dates = unique(df$Start_Date)
        
        Filtered_Dates <- df_xts[xts::endpoints(
            df_xts,
            on = input$Frequency
        )] %>% xts_to_tibble()
        
        output$Time_Series_UI <- renderUI({
            sliderInput("Date", "Date:",
                        min = pull(slice_min(Filtered_Dates, date), date),
                        max = pull(slice_max(Filtered_Dates, date), date),
                        value = pull(slice_min(Filtered_Dates, date), date),
                        step = 1,
                        #timeFormat = "%YYYY-%MM-%DD",
                        animate = T
            )
        })
    })
    
    # Filter data for the date selected
    Filtered_Data <- reactive({
        req(input$Date)
        filter(df, Date == input$Date)
    })
    
    
    # Create the leaflet map
    output$Time_Series_Map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(df) %>%
            addTiles() %>%
            setView(lat = 0, lng = 0, zoom = 2)
    })
    
    # Create data markers for selected date
    observe({
        # print(input$Date)
        
        leafletProxy("Time_Series_Map", data = Filtered_Data()) %>%
            addCircleMarkers(
                lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat,
                popup = ~id
            )
    })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I added a little button on the bottom left of the map. when it is clicked, the plot is zoomed to full screen and in full screen, click it again will go back to normal view.

- All you need to do is place your plot components inside a parent or grandparent or grand-grand...parent component which has `class = "leaflet-full-screen"`.
- Change the `.plot-zoom` style if you don't like the button position or color etc.
- Include the style and script tags in your app. Usually you want to have the style close to the top (head) of your app and place the script after leaflet tags.
- This works on multiple leaflet objects, so it means it will add the button to all leaflet maps in your app.

See my similar answer how we can do the same thing with [plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69042546/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-full-screen-popup-window-of-a-plotly-chart-in-r). The code is a little different though.

[image]

Comment: @Iz100, thanks so much can you also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992103/show-data-points-only-for-selected-date-on-a-slider-via-leaflet-in-r-shiny) question? The code is the same as this question

Answer (score 1):

The [shinyfullscreen](https://github.com/etiennebacher/shinyfullscreen) package offers a very simple solution to this problem. It was recently [updated](https://github.com/etiennebacher/shinyfullscreen/issues/5) to include a full screen button that can work on individual charts or toggle your entire Shiny App between full screen and normal view.

You can install the development version by running the code below:

```
devtools::install_github("etiennebacher/shinyfullscreen")
```