# How to add fullscreen icon to a plotly chart modebar in Python Dash App

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to add fullscreen option in plotly modebar to all my plotly's chart in a python Dash app. I've seen a lot of custom code snippets to achieve it in R ou JS. However, I can't find something similar in python for Dash app. Can someone help me?

I've found this trick in JS that would be perfect if it could be embedded/adapted in python for dash app : https://gist.github.com/p1-rde/2120938f1c7f44c26755cfd83f8562e8 . Or this one in R : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69096923/23027270

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or where are you stuck ?